# Find filenames using variables in a for loop in UNIX

Tags: for-loop, awk, find, sh, filenames

I have some files of this form: **2014.144.09.27.56.0195.IU.SDV.00.BHZ.M.SAC** and I want to extract the **SDV**, **00** ,**BHZ** variables, in order to find a file, of this form  **./POLEZEROFILES/SAC_PZs_IU_SDV_BHZ_00_2014.112.19.50.00.0000_2599.365.23.59.59.99999**, using these variables. I am using this forloop, that for every ".SAC" file, it finds the corresponding "SAC_PZs_" file, with the same variables in the filename.

```
#!/bin/sh
ALIST=(*SAC)

for ((i=0;i<${#ALIST[@]};i++));do

A="${ALIST[i]}"

staname=`ls "$A" | awk -F"[_.]" '{print $8}'`
staXX=`ls "$A" | awk -F"[_.]" '{print $9}'`
stacomp=`ls "$A" | awk -F"[_.]" '{print $10}'`

B=`find ./POLEZEROFILES -name "SAC*_${staname}_*${stacomp}_*${staXX}*" -print`
echo "${A}" "${B}"
done
```

This code works for some filenames, but in some cases it outputs 2 filenames, ignoring the **00** variable.For example,

for this `$A`:

```
2014.144.09.27.33.0195.IU.RSSD.00.BHZ.M.SAC
```

it outputs 2 `$B`:

> ./POLEZEROFILES/SAC_PZs_IU_RSSD_BHZ_**10**_2011.209.05.56.00.0000_2599.365.23.59.59.99999
>
> ./POLEZEROFILES/SAC_PZs_IU_RSSD_BHZ_**00**_2011.208.18.13.59.0000_2599.365.23.59.59.99999

The second output is the right one.
Can anyone figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not related to your problem but a general comment. You don't need `ls` in those awk lines. `echo` will work just fine (as will `awk ... <<<"$A"`).

Your problem is that your pattern matches too loosely.

Your second to last `*` consumes up to the `00.0000....` bit in your first filename and then matches. You need to anchor your desired patterns better. So if you know that `stacomp` and `staXX` will be next to each other drop the `*` between them. If you don't know that then at least put a `_` after `staXX` to anchor the following character.

There's also no need for the array and manual for loop here.

Just `for A in *SAC; do` will work for your loop.

Comment: Newbie says "Thank you for all your corrections!It worked fine!"!